# Site.createExternalUser() returning null

Tags: apex, community, administration

While I am creating a Community User through an apex call to `SiteSite.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password)`, the method is returning `null`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Yes, it really sucks that Site.createExternalUser's only communication concerning failure or success, is its return value: null or not null. So many things can go wrong, but it does not give any clues what went wrong. The log is also empty. It's a black box! Does the owner of the account have a role? It is required. Is the required nick name unique?

Comment: I ended up replacing the call to createExternalUser with inserts of an Account and a User record, as well as associating the two of them by filling the User ContactId field. I hope that is all the required functionality. It looks good, so far, because I can navigate between the newly created Account and User records.

Answer (score 1):

This means that it had some kind of problem creating the user.

- Check that all of your user fields are valid.
- Check that the owner of the account is valid (and has the right permissions).
- Check that the password you set for the user follows the rules. You can check your org's password policies in Setup.

It's probably the last one, since `insert user` doesn't require a password, so if that works then that's the problem.